# I have a square grid of cells and all cells in my program are in each of my outer arraylist elements. I only ant a proportion of them in each element

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

So within my program, I have a 2D grid of cells, I have an ArrayList which stores the cells called 'columns', and I have a 2D array which stores the ArrayList of cells called 'rows'. The thing is, all cells of my columns ArrayList are being stored in each row element. I don't know why it's doing this.

```
\\JPanel class

public class Frame extends JPanel {
    private ArrayList<Cell> columns;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Cell>> rows;
    private int cellLength;
    private Color dead;
    public Frame(){
        rows=new ArrayList<>();
        columns= new ArrayList<>();
        this.setSize(new Dimension(900, 900));
        this.cellLength=200;
        this.dead=Color.BLACK;
        createMap();
    }

    public void createMap(){
            for(int columsi=0;columsi<getHeight()/cellLength;columsi++){
                for(int rowsi=0;rowsi<getHeight()/cellLength;rowsi++){

                    Cell c=new Cell(rowsi*(cellLength+1),columsi*(cellLength+1),cellLength,false);
                    columns.add(c);
                }
                rows.add(columns);

        }
        System.out.println(rows.get(3).size());
    }

}
```

What I expect is each arraylist of Cells get added to each row element every time the outer loop iterates, but ALL cells end up in ALL the row elements, so the total size returned from the command `(row.get(3).size)` is 16 whereas I want it to be 4.

Edit: Solution found. Taken out redundant code.

Comment: You are adding the same column list multiple times to the rows list. You need to create a new list for each row. `for (...) { ArrayList<Cell> columns = new ArrayList<>(); for (...) { Cell c = new Cell(...); columns.add(c); } rows.add(columns); }`

Comment: I understand the problem, thank you

Comment: And your solution works.